# creating tuples from infinite list

Tags: haskell

When trying to solve [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/81253/swap-prime-exponents-with-their-neighbours) I stumbled upon something I was not able to explain myself.

First I generate an infinite list of prime numbers as follows:

```
primes = [n|n<-[2..],product[1..n-1]`rem`n==n-1]
```

This has the inferred type `[Integer]` so Int-overflow should not be a problem.

Then I try to make 2-tuples of subsequent primes (goal: `[(2,3),(5,7),...]`). To achieve this I wrote another function:

```
listtotuples l=[ (l!!i, l!!(i+1) ) |i<-[0,2..]]
```

Strangely this `listtotuples` function seems to work fine on e.g. `[0..]`, but it just stops working when I apply it to `primes`, the output is just (after interrupting)

```
[(2,3),(5,7),(11,13),(Interrupted.
```

I do not understand why this happens, can anyone explain?

**EDIT:** This does not only happen when trying to output the infinite list, but also e.g. using `take 10 $ listtotuples primes` in Prelude after having loaded a file with the two lines from above. It does get stuck at the exact same point.

I am using Windows 7 with GHCi 7.10.2.

**EDIT2:** The full contents of my file are as follows:

```
order p m=head[n-1|n<-[0..],mod m (p^n)>0] 
primes = [n|n<-[2..],product[1..n-1]`rem`n==n-1]
listtotuples l=[ (l!!i, l!!(i+1) ) |i<-[0,2..]]
p=listtotuples primes
f n=product[r^(order s n) * s^(order r n)|(r,s)<-take n p]
```

The problem disappears as soon as I comment/remove the last line (the function `f`, but I still think this is very strange, as `f` is not called and does not have anything todo with the functions above. Also if I replace `take n p` in the function `f` with `[(2,3)]` everything works as defined.

Comment: It's much more efficient to write `listToTuples xs@(_:xs') = zip xs xs'`

Comment: BTW: I cannot reproduce your problem: `Prelude> take 10 $ listToTuples primes
[(2,3),(5,7),(11,13),(17,19),(23,29),(31,37),(41,43),(47,53),(59,61),(67,71)]
`  (using your implementation for `listToTuples`).

Comment: @Bakuriu Thank you for the hint (I'm obviously still a beginner). On my computer it does still get stuck at the exact same point even when using `take 10 $ listToTuples primes`. What OS / versio nare you using?

Comment: @Carsten Yes this still does not work. I did update the question accordingly. PS: To the people voting to close: Why do you consider this question off topic?

Comment: @Bakuriu That behaves differently -- note that `(l !! 1, l !! 2)` is *not* in the output of `listtotuples`, but `(xs !! 1, xs !! 2)` does appear in the output of `listToTuples`. [`chunksOf 2`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.2/docs/Data-List-Split.html#v:chunksOf) is a better replacement.

Comment: @flawr Are you sure that the code you're executing is exactly the code you've posted here? e.g. is your editor looking at the right file, have you definitely hit save, etc.?

Comment: For what it's worth, I have not yet voted to close. I read the proposed reason ("typo/not reproducible") to mean that even the person who posted the question can no longer reproduce the problem. Just because we can't reproduce it doesn't mean it isn't a problem -- just that we haven't yet figured out what the problem could be in a way that lets us reproduce it. We may need more information; but what, exactly? Unless somebody has a concrete suggestion for what's missing, I don't think the "no MWE" reason for closing applies, either.

Comment: @DanielWagner Thank you, now we are on the right track. I've had another (unrelated) function in the file. If I comment that function out, the problem dissappears. Still very strange, I updated the question again. Right now I'm trying to figure out why the presence of `f` causes this problem.

Comment: @DanielWagner Yes I know. I just wanted to show a different approach that didn't involve `!!` which is generally an evil operation. The correct alternative for infinite lists could be `listToTuples (x:y:xs) = (x,y) : listToTuples xs` which is more or less what `chunksOf 2` does (except that produces lists instead of tuples and works with finite lists too)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The addition of `f` forces your primes to have type `Int`, which does overflow during the factorial operation. The reasoning goes like this:

1. `take :: Int -> [a] -> [a]`
2. In `f n`, the use of `take n p` forces `n :: Int`.
3. Because the arguments to `order` must have the same type, the calls `order r n` and `order s n` force `r, s :: Int`.
4. `(r, s) <- take n p` forces `p :: [(Int, Int)]`
5. `p = listtotuples primes` forces `primes :: [Int]`

Simple fixes include breaking steps 2 or 3 above; use `take (fromInteger n) p` to break step 2 or `order s (fromIntegral n)` and `order r (fromIntegral n)` to break step 3.

...and now you know why adding top-level type signatures is considered a best practice. =)

Comment: Thank you very much your answer (and your patience)! I now learned that I should check my types more. (But type signatures are so wasteful in *code-golf* =)